# Does smtpd_tls_CApath have precedence over smtpd_tls_CAfile or vice versa in postfix?

Tags: ssl, postfix

I am configuring a postfix server (Version 3.3.1 on CentOS 8)

If I configure both, smtpd_tls_CAfile and smtpd_tls_CApath, will postfix load all the certificates or will it choose one of the options over the other?

I can't tell from the documentation here: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_CApath

Answer (score 2):

Based on [the source code](https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/blob/bf6bdb562df0c82968a4522feba0ab9777bca4d8/postfix/src/tls/tls_certkey.c#L517) it will accept both arguments and use these to call the OpenSSL function [SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html). This function will add both path and file to the SSL context and both will be checked for trusted CA when validating a certificate. In other words: these arguments are not exclusive but both values are considerd.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the bad old days, some operating systems would ship trusted CA certificates in separate files, all placed in some directory. This is the directory you would use with `smtpd_tls_CApath`.

This far into the 21st century virtually all Linux distributions ship a pre-built single file containing every trusted CA certificate. Its location varies by Linux distribution, but wherever it is placed, it is the file name you would use with `smtpd_tls_CAfile`.

These options are mutually exclusive. You will only use one of them, depending on how your operating system ships its trusted CA certificates. Most likely it will be `smtpd_tls_CAfile`. On CentOS 8, the CA certificate bundle is located at `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`, giving you the `main.cf` configuration:

```
smtpd_tls_CAfile=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```